# How to integrate automatic payment charged in ionic with paypal using credit card

Tags: paypal, ionic3, paypal-rest-sdk

I’m developing a delivery application that will work with PayPal for payments. Ionic/Cordova has a native library that makes things easy, yet the flow is not the way i’d like it to be.

With “PayPal-Cordova-Plugin”, the authentication window opens for every payment and the user must click the button to confirm the payment.

What I would like to implement was something more direct, transparent. The user would authenticate with PayPal within my application and with the probable token that would receive this authentication, I would execute the checkout requests (an example would be the payment by PayPal on Uber).

With the PayPal developer documentation I could not find a way to perform this implementation on Ionic, so I would like help with that.

Answer (score 0):

The old PayPal Mobile SDKs used by the cordova plugin are ancient. Do not use those. Do not use those for anything. If you try to use those, you are going to have a bad time.

The first paragraph at the top of the Readme of https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin points you to the things you should be using instead.

As is mentioned there, PayPal Express Checkout via the Braintree Mobile SDK is a worldwide option for those who need a native SDK. It is documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/

You will need a webservice for the server-side portion.

Comment: I want to charge customer credit card automatically when the rider finish the ride ,credit card info of customer is already saved in the database, i want that credit card to charged automatically without having customer to click any button.is this possible in brainstree ?Please let me know

Comment: With just the out of the box Express Checkout via Braintree, no. You'll need reference transactions added to your PayPal business account, or the full Braintree Gateway service (from braintreegateway.com) which has reference transactions / billing agreement functionality.